# Form automatically adds entry on page load

Tags: php, html, forms, input, label

Trying to set up a form with PHP but I want it to wait until the submit button is pressed to run the script. Otherwise it does so every time the page loads and spams the box which is on the same page. I know next to nothing about PHP! Thanks for any and all help!

```
<div style="height:75%;width:90%;border:1px solid #ccc;overflow:auto;background-color: rgba(50, 54, 57, 0.8);color: white;">
 <?php
 

    $msg = $_POST["msg"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $posts = file_get_contents("posts.txt");
    $posts = "<i>$msg</i> - $name ($date)<br />" . $posts;
    file_put_contents("posts.txt", $posts);
    echo $posts;
    

 ?>




</div>
<font color="white">
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
 <label>Quote
 <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" />
 </label>
 <label>Name
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
 </label>
 <label>Date
 <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
 </label>
 
</font>

<font color="white">
 <p>
 <label>Submit
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
 </label>
 </p>
 </form>
</font>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will execute all the time because, there is nothing which checks whether the form is submitted or not.

You add condition to check that,

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $msg = $_POST["msg"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $posts = file_get_contents("posts.txt");
    $posts = "<i>$msg</i> - $name ($date)<br />" . $posts;
    file_put_contents("posts.txt", $posts);
    echo $posts;
   }
```

Now it checks if there is any value in the `$_POST` array with the key `submit`.
By the way, the `submit` key comes from the `name` property of submit input button in html.

`<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />`